# nested folders in Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script

We have a few email accounts at work that are shared by number of people and a silly policy of emails older then 365 days old being automatically purged. So we need to back up all email correspondence by saving them as pdf to Google Drive.

Once a task is completed than all relating emails are moved into a folder. The script I have takes care of saving the emails. But I'd like to replicate the Google inbox nested folder structure in Google Drive with the script to save emails in the appropriate folder.

Example:

2015/North/city 1/email

[inbox folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99Pfp.jpg)

thanks in advance

Comment: is your question related to reading the folder structure in Gmail or creating the folder structure in Google Drive. Please try to add some more details to your question.

Comment: @Josep reading the folder structure in Gmail and recreating in Google drive    ..........   The email is in "2015/North/City 1" in Gmail and want to save it in the identical folder structure in Google Drive

Answer (score 0):

**The email is in "2015/North/City 1" in Gmail and want to save it in the identical folder structure in Google Drive**

The pseudo code is:-

1. Find "2015"
2. If not exists, create it
3. Save ID of 2015
4. Find "North" with a parent of 2015's ID
5. If not exists, create it
6. Save ID of North
7. Find "City" with a parent of North's ID
8. If not exists, create it
9. Save ID of City
10. Create your email with City's ID as its parent

It's also possible to fetch all folders in a single query, and then construct your own hierarchy in memory, but since you're using AppScript, network latency shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: @pinoyid  There are 8 people who have access to the email account creating their own labels/folders so hard coding labels is not on option.... the script should be able to read and reread all folders/labels as it runs and recreate the sctructure

Comment: I know. I only used the hardcoded labels from your question. Are you saying you don't know how to parse the tags from gmail?

Comment: @pinoyid yes, how to parse the labels so I can create folders

Comment: You should probably post that as a new question and tag it [gmail-api]